# Img click not working

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have javascript.js file  with this code

```
$(document).ready(function() {$('#rabbit').click(function (e) {
    var offset = $(this).offset(),
        left = e.pageX - offset.left,
        top = e.pageY - offset.top;
    if (top > $(this).height() / 2) {
        alertDiv('You\'ve cliked under the middle.', 'alert-white');
    } else {
        alertDiv('You\'ve cliked above the middle.', 'alert-gray');
    }
        });
}); 
function alertDiv(text, cssClass) {
    var alrt = $('<div class="alert ' + cssClass + '">' + text + '</div>');
    $(document.body).append(alrt);
    alrt.click(function () {
        alrt.remove();
   });
}
```

and in the css file I have this

```
.alert {
    position: absolute;
    left: 30px;
    top: 30px;
    width: 300px;
    height: 200px;
    border: 1px solid black;
}
.alert-white {
    background: white;
}
.alert-gray {
    background: #ccc;
}
```

and then lastly in my html file, I include these

```
<LINK href="main.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
<script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.0.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="javascript.js"></script>
```

and then lastly do this

```
<img src="http://www.clermontanimal.net/images/lop_rabbit_easter.jpg" id="rabbit" alt="" />
```

I included everything I need but when I click the picture it's still not working.
I got this code from
http://jsfiddle.net/htEvT/2/

What am I forgetting?

Comment: The image click works for me. What browser are you using?

Comment: Try replacing you first script for: `<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.0.0/jquery.min.js"></script>`

Comment: Oh god the first script I was including was the problem. Thank You!

Comment: Ah good catch @WilfredoP . That would be why the fiddle works but his version doesn't.

Comment: It works for me in chrome and firefox

Answer (score 0):

If you are working on with a file:// url, the non-protocol format url will try to obtain the file from `file://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.0.0/jquery.min.js`.

Use

`http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.0.0/jquery.min.js`

or

`https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.0.0/jquery.min.js` instead.

Answer (score -1):

Try to include the jquery tag in head and refer your script at the bottom of the body.
Not sure though. Did you check for console errors.
And referal should be like
`<script src="https:/..."></script>` since you are giving a live url instead of local one

Comment: Realy nice to see guys downvoting without mentioning the reason.